# Как написать функцию с неопределенным количеством аргументов на C++?

Tags: c++, функции, шаблоны-с++

Задание:

> Написать функцию sum с переменным числом параметров, которая находит сумму чисел типа int по формуле:
> `S=a1*a2+a2*a3+a3*a4+. . . . .`
> Написать вызывающую функцию main, которая обращается к функции sum не менее трех раз с количеством параметров 5, 10, 12

Не могу понять как вообще это cstdarg работает. Как я понимаю все это дело какой древний рудимент C?
Какие есть альтернативы для решения задачи?

Comment: Так вам надо через stdarg или именно средствами C++ (шаблоны)? Определитесь точнее... это совершенно разные подходы. P.S. Вопрос исправлен и теперь звучит совсем не так, как изначально. Ответ на очередную версию вопроса: использование `stdarg` и шаблоны. Можно, конечно, написать N разных функций  :), но это вариант, прямо скажем, не очень... Да, насколько критично требование "только `int`"?

Comment: Могли бы вы расписать как можно решить эту задачу средствами C++

Answer (score 4):

Простейшее решение с `stdarg`:

```
int sum(int count, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap,count);
    int Sum = 0;
    int a = va_arg(ap,int);
    for(int i = 1; i < count; ++i)
    {
        int b = va_arg(ap,int);
        Sum += a*b;
        a = b;
    }
    va_end(ap);
    return Sum;
}


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    cout << sum(5,1,2,3,4,5) << endl;
}
```

С шаблонами набросал на коленке (т.е. не то, что допускаю — уверен, что может быть более красивый вариант) так:

```
int SumAux(int a0, int S, int x)
{
    return S + a0*x;
}

template<typename... Args>
auto SumAux(int a0, int S, int x, Args... args)
{
    S += a0 * x;
    return SumAux(x, S, args...);
}

template<typename... Args>
auto Sum(int x, int y, Args... args)
{
    return SumAux(x,0,y,args...);
}


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    cout << Sum(1,2,3,4,5) << endl;
}
```

Чуть покороче — две `SumAux` заменяются одной:

```
template<typename... Args>
auto SumAux(int a0, int S, int x, Args... args)
{
    S += a0 * x;
    if constexpr (sizeof...(args) == 0) return S;
    else return SumAux(x, S, args...);
}
```

Comment: Там местами умножение имеется...

Comment: @maestro Не обратил внимания, буду переделывать...

Comment: Шаблонный вариант куда проще (не считая другие достоинства), чем вариант названный простейшим решением(нет?)

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Ну, это скорее вопрос вкуса. Лично мне первый вариант представляется более простым. Как минимум, он без вспомогательных функций :)

Comment: @Harry,  без учета  "С шаблонами набросал на коленке (т.е. не то, что допускаю — уверен, что может быть более красивый вариант)" может быть, хотя я сторонник того, что пора навсегда забыть про сишный вариант

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Другое дело, что первый вариант в данном случае (когда значения известны во время компиляции) все равно разворачивается в вызов функции, а вот второй вычисляется сразу при компиляции :) Что есть, то есть...

Comment: @Harry,  мой вопрос не являлся замечанием, а желанием понять почему я могу быть не прав.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Да я же не говорю, что вы неправы :) Просто мне этот вопрос представляется скорее вопросом вкуса (при аккуратной работе... Троеточие вещь небезопасная...).

Comment: А если уж использовать `if constexpr`, то почему не сделать всё за одну шаблонную функцию? Что-то вроде: `int s = 0; if constexpr(sizeof...(args) > 0) s = Sum(y, args...); return x*y + s;`.

Comment: @needKVAS Ну, это вы придумали :) Почему бы вам не добавить в свой ответ второй вариант?..

Comment: Мой ответ не про это. Это скорее развитие вашей идеи.

Answer (score 3):

В случае одинаковых типов аргументов шаблона можно для простоты превращать их в какой-нибудь вектор:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <class... Args>
int sum(const Args&... args) {
    std::vector<int> a{static_cast<int>(args)...};
    const int count = a.size()-1;
    int out = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        out+=a[i]*a[i+1];
    }
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << sum(1,2,3,4,5) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sum(1,2,3.2,4,5) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```